# rewriteBatchedStatements introduces Syntax Error

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm optimizing some SQL queries. And I've written them to use batches. Integration tests run fine, and everything is happy. But then I learn that MySQL doesn't give a performance increase unless rewriteBatchedStatements is enabled.

So I modified my connection string to include rewriteBatchedStatement, but I start getting a MySQLSytaxErrorException. When I remove rewriteBatchedStatement from the connection String, the exception goes away.

SQL: `INSERT INTO rawdata.scales (ID, NAME) VALUES (?, ?)`

Exception:

`` com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ';INSERT INTO rawdata.scales` at line 1 ``

Curiously, this only happens on the first SQL statement that runs in the tests I've setup. All the others run fine.

Why would enabling this feature add a semi-colon to the front of my SQL?

Comment: Please show the code you use, and not just the query. Also mention the version of MySQL Connector/J you are using.

Answer (score 6):

There is a known issue in Connector/J 5.1.40 up to and including at least 5.1.43 which causes MySQLSytaxErrorException to be thrown on inserts when rewriteBatchedStatement is enabled.

See https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=84813

I have been able to reproduce this in statements with a trailing semicolon, e.g.

```
INSERT INTO rawdata.scales (ID, NAME) VALUES (?, ?);
```

Removing the trailing semicolon fixes the issue in my case.